# Convert pdf into Image Eye file

Tags: gnome

I need to convert **pdf** files into files with extension **iei** which is [Image Eye thumbnail cache file](http://www.file-extensions.org/iei-file-extension). How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

[.iei](http://www.file-extensions.org/iei-file-extension) is not a standard image format, it's a thumbnail cache for Image Eye program (which, btw, seems to be Windows-only).

I'm pretty sure nobody bothered to write a converter, so your only option is to write a program yourself.